# Using JQuery to add <div>before a large list of existing <div>'s and </div> after

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry I'm a bit new to JQuery - I've done some reading on how to add elements to existing elements using JQuery but I'm struggling with the following:

I have a large list of div elements on a page all with unique classes - for example

```
<div class="example">content</div>
<div class="example1">content</div>
<div class="example2">content</div>
<div class="example3">content</div>
<div class="example4">content</div>
<div class="example5">content</div>
<div class="example6">content</div>
<div class="example7">content</div>
<div class="example8">content</div>
```

The list is a lot longer and doesn't use "example" - they are different so I can't match on "example x"

What I want to do is use wrapall() to add a div before and after certain existing div's so I end up with

```
<div class="new-class">
<div class="example">content</div>
<div class="example1">content</div>
<div class="example2">content</div>
<div class="example3">content</div>
<div class="example4">content</div>
</div>
<div class="example5">content</div>
<div class="example6">content</div>
<div class="example7">content</div>
<div class="example8">content</div>
```

I've read that I can do the following

```
$('.example, .example1, .example2, .example3, .example4').wrapAll('<div class="new-class" />');
```

But my list is huge and I don't want to have to add each div individially if I don't need to...
Is there a way of saying "wrappAll between .example & .example4" (as per my example above)

Thanks

Comment: Are there any parent elements? If not and you want to wrap first nth divs then you can use `$("div").slice(0,5).wrapAll()`

Comment: What is the criteria for deciding which elements to wrap?

Comment: There isn't a criteria other than what I choose...

Comment: @MuhammadBilal how does that work? It looks like it splits the list of <div>'s in half? I suppose I could count the div's and do it that way but it wouldn't be an equal split - evetuntually I want to have say 30 divs in one parent div and another 40 in another parent div etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: [nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) is EXCLUDING the *to* element

jQuery >= 3: [addBack()](https://api.jquery.com/addBack/)

```js
$(".example").nextUntil(".example5").addBack().wrapAll("<div class='newClass'/>")
```

```css
.newClass { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">content</div>
<div class="example1">content</div>
<div class="example2">content</div>
<div class="example3">content</div>
<div class="example4">content</div>
<div class="example5">content</div>
<div class="example6">content</div>
<div class="example7">content</div>
<div class="example8">content</div>
```

jQuery < 3: [andSelf()](https://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)

```js
$(".example").nextUntil(".example5").andSelf().wrapAll("<div class='newClass'/>")
```

```css
.newClass { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">content</div>
<div class="example1">content</div>
<div class="example2">content</div>
<div class="example3">content</div>
<div class="example4">content</div>
<div class="example5">content</div>
<div class="example6">content</div>
<div class="example7">content</div>
<div class="example8">content</div>
```

Without naming the divs we can use [slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```js
let start = 0, end = 5; // from - to including needs +1
$("div").slice(start,end+1).wrapAll("<div class='newClass'/>")
```

```css
.newClass { color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example0">content 0</div>
<div class="example1">content 1</div>
<div class="example2">content 2</div>
<div class="example3">content 3</div>
<div class="example4">content 4</div>
<div class="example5">content 5</div>
<div class="example6">content 6</div>
<div class="example7">content 7</div>
<div class="example8">content 8</div>
```